# Problem with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

This statement doesnt work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p').css( {'color':'Black', 'background-color':'Red'});
```

```
<p > DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</p>
```

why?.. no red background appears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/8f030.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('p').css( {'color':'Black', 'background-color':'Red'});
</script>
```

you have to close `<script>` and you can remove `$(document).ready`

Comment: Bad practice. You should stay with document ready, it's natural way for starting scripts in jquery. This solution could cause that script will be run late that it can (if lot of loading on page). The problem was unclosed document ready function call.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('p').css( {color:'Black', backgroundColor:'Red'});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CAarv/1/

you can use `backgroundColor` [REF](http://api.jquery.com/css/) or if you want to use background-color use the quotes around them like `'background-color'`

```
   $('p').css( {color:'Black', 'background-color':'Red'});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CAarv/4/

Comment: deleted comment after posting jsfiddle. but @Dmitry whole code is in my answer (with explain)

Comment: i thought the OP copied the code from the source so somwhere in his code he might have closed the `</script>`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe tou have error in javascript somewhere and it stops runing ? Or other event overwrite this very fast so you don't see.

Error of parsing - not closed document ready `});` in your sample.

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to have closed your braces. Try the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p').css( {'color':'Black', 'background-color':'Red'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not closed curly brackets?
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('p').css( {'color':'Black', 'background-color':'Red'});
});
```